# How to enable support for Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites on Windows Server

Tags: encryption, ssl

SSL lab test provides grade B for one of my websites due to AEAD issue. I was wondering how we could enable AEAD support to improve the grading to A.

I am using windows server 2008 R2, TLS1.2 is enabled. I tried IIS Crypto [nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto] and not been able to resolve the issue. "This server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites. Grade capped to B. " is the only comment I get from Qualys SSL lab test result.

Comment: Guys, first time user. I cannot cast close votes, but please only hit the close button, not the downvote button.

Comment: As @MaartenBodewes mentioned, there needs to be a more information here before this is answerable.  For a start:  What web server are you using?  What is the exact issue SSLLabs reported?

Comment: I am using windows server 2008 R2, TLS1.2 is enabled. I tried IIS Crypto [https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto] and not been able to resolve the issue. "This server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites. Grade capped to B. " is the only comment I get from Qualys SSL lab test result.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using IIS Crypto as well and same issue.  What I've found, by accident, is you probably need to Apply the Server Defaults with no reboot required.  *THEN* apply the best practices or your configuration settings.  After I do that, I'm able to get past the B "cap" for AEAD.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409745/712526) on SO is a lot more specific, but it's also for Server 2012. (Haven't tried it, yet.)

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you use RSA certificate move the TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher suites to the top
if you use ECC certificate move the TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher suites to the top